# GHCi runtime linker: fatal error

Tags: haskell, directory, gtk, ghci

I have installed gtk. The two modules
System.Console.Readline and Graphics.UI.Gtk works normally separately. But when i import the two modules in the same code, when ghci loads all packages, shows me:

```
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.4.3.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-1.2.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package utf8-string-1.0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package cairo-0.13.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package glib-0.13.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package gio-0.13.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unix-2.5.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.2.4.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.2.3.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pango-0.13.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package gtk-0.13.9 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.1.0.2 ... 

GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   __hscore_S_IXUSR
whilst processing object file
   /usr/lib/ghc/directory-1.1.0.2/HSdirectory-1.1.0.2.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: `ghci` is loading two versions of `directory`: `directory-1.2.4.0` and `directory-1.1.0.2` I don't think it is fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Yuras' answer, either unregister the unused package, or hide it.
To unregister, use (for example)

```
ghc-pkg unregister directory-1.1.0.2
```

You can also hide the package when starting ghci. For example:

```
ghci -hide-package directory-1.1.0.2
```